# Change ColumnWidth of Datagrid which is filled per Itemsource .net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a Datagrid which is filled with a Datatable:

```
Dim dataTable as new Datatable
Dim dataGrid as new DataGrid
```

Then i filled the Datatable with Data and displayed it in the Datagrid.

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView
```

Everythings fine.

But now i want to change the Width of some Columns like:

```
datagrid.columns(0).Width = 100
```

-> Error: Index out of Bound Exception. -> There is no Column in Datagrid.

But i can see that their are Columns. When i set the ItemsSource it doesn´t add Columns automatically?!

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: Important: I created the Datagrid in the code, so i cant resolve the problem in the xaml.

Comment: Is the DataGrid automatically generating the columns for you?

Comment: `column` is not a property of `datagrid` for info on how to set the width see example [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?230614-How-to-adjust-the-column-width-in-a-datagrid)

Comment: @Glen Thomas autogenerateColumns = true, when i change it to false i dont see any data in my Datagrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event to modify your columns:

```
'Access and update columns during autogeneration 
Private Sub DG1_AutoGeneratingColumn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs)
    Dim headername As String = e.Column.Header.ToString()
    'Cancel the column you don't want to generate 
    If headername = "IDontWantThisColumn" Then
        e.Cancel = True 
    End If 

    'update column details when generating 
    If headername = "MyFirstColumn" Then
        e.Column.Width = 100 
    ElseIf headername = "MySecondColumn" Then
        e.Column.Width = 120 
    End If 
End Sub
```